# Error when trying to set base path mapping to custom domain in API Gateway (Mixing of REST APIs and HTTP APIs on the same domain...)

Tags: aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

I am using CDK to add a custom domain to an existing API Gateway and set the base path mapping.

the adding of the custom domain works, but I get an error I don't understand.
I tried following the api gw docs:
https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/blob/master/packages/%40aws-cdk/aws-apigateway/README.md
but I get this error.

This is my code:

```
api_gateway: RestApi = RestApi.from_rest_api_id(scope=self, 
                                                id='ApiGatewayFromId', 
                                                rest_api_id=<my rest api id>)
cert_arn = get_cert_arn('mydomain.com', <region>)
cert = Certificate.from_certificate_arn(scope=self, id='SomeDomainCert', 
                                        certificate_arn=cert_arn)

domain = DomainName(scope=self,
                id='APIGatewayDomainName',
                certificate=cert,
                domain_name='mydomain.com',
                endpoint_type=EndpointType.REGIONAL,
                security_policy=SecurityPolicy.TLS_1_2)

domain.add_base_path_mapping(target_api=api_gateway, base_path='v1')
```

And this is my error:

> Mixing of REST APIs and HTTP APIs on the same domain name can only be accomplished through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface. Currently, WebSocket APIs can only be attached to a domain name with other WebSocket APIs. This must also occur through API Gateway's V2 DomainName interface. (Service: AmazonApiGateway; Status Code: 400; Error Code: BadRequestException;

I also tried this, with the same result:

```
    base_path_mapping = BasePathMapping(scope=self,
                                id="TestBasePathMapping",
                                domain_name=domain,
                                rest_api=api_gateway)
```

I'm not sure what mixing i'm doing and what websockets has to do here. am I really supposed to use the v2 interface? 
that documentation doesn't indicate this, and it mentions using add_base_path_mapping for this purpose.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Hu past me, future you here.
While I can't explain why this error occurs, as indicated in the error, using the V2 api works.
here's a working code snippet:

```
cert_arn = get_cert_arn('mydomain.com', <region>)

domain_name_properties = CfnDomainNameV2. \
DomainNameConfigurationProperty(certificate_arn=cert_arn,
                            certificate_name=<cert name>,  # I Used 'mydomain.com' as the name of the domain cert
                            endpoint_type=str(EndpointType.REGIONAL))

domain_name = CfnDomainNameV2(scope=self, id='APIGatewayDomainNameV2',
                      domain_name='mydomain.com',
                      domain_name_configurations=[domain_name_properties])

api_mapping = CfnApiMapping(scope=self, id="APIGatewayApiMapping1",
                    api_id=<rest api id>,
                    domain_name='mydomain.com',
                    stage='v1',
                    api_mapping_key='something')
```